# how to connect to mysql using strongloop

Tags: javascript, mysql, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a table on my server . is it possible to get this data and pass it to strongloop? How should i do it? i've searched that there has something to do with the connector? but it seems that i cant do it. can someone guide me how to do it since this is my first time doing the strongloop. it seems that this is powerful

```
accounts
name   |   position
john   |   president
chris  |   manager
```

also i dont get the use of the model? and the datasource? even though i manage to somehow make it run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vincent,

Have you looked at the examples here - http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Example+applications

There are simple applications here including a simple mysql applictaion that explains how to connect your data via a connector.

https://github.com/strongloop-community/loopback-mysql-example

You can peruse the forum threads here too.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs

hth